# Reading the output of cox fitter to compare two different runs

Tags: survival, cox-model

Can anyone help me in reading the output of the Cox fitter of lifelines? im having trouble understanding it...

basically, im trying to determine which of the model works better:
the first one is run only with one feature - "pam50 + claudin-low subtype"
the other one is run with two features as seen in the picture below.

how can i determine which one of those performs better at its task?

EDIT: By better i mean, which model has a better estimations of the variables that the hazard function is derived from?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: "im trying to determine which of the model works better" - you may need to define what "better" means to you (this may be application dependent). What is your goal with the analysis?

Comment: Please edit your question to address the comment by@Cam.Davidson.Pilon about how you intend to use the results of your model. Also, it's not clear that you have provided enough details about the models themselves and the corresponding output for both of them to provide a helpful answer. It would be best if you could include the function calls and outputs from the models as `code` by pasting in the text and then using the `{}` tool to format it properly as code. Otherwise, it's very hard to read for many and impossible for those who use text-to-speech conversion.